# can't open tensorboard 0.0.0.0:6006 or localhost:6006

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

when i use tensorboard in cmd with win10

D:\python document\tensorflow>tensorboard --logdir=D:\python document\tensorflow
Starting TensorBoard b'47' at http://0.0.0.0:6006

But when i open the webpage，it shows

"dial tcp 0.0.0.0:6006: connectex: The requested address is not valid in its context."

and i tried localhost:6006 then,and it shows

"No scalar data was found."

so what should i do now

Comment: when opened localhost:6006, is that showed the tensorboard, where do you get error  "No scalar data was found". I think your path to train log is wrong.

Answer (score 56):

Refer to [tensorflow issue#9701](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9701).

Run `tensorboard --logdir=YOUR_LOG_DIR --host=127.0.0.1` in command prompt,
and type `localhost:6006` in chrome, this works for me (Win10, anaconda4.3.16, python3.5.3, tensorflow1.1.0).

Comment: add a tips: you shoud replace `log_dir` as your own `log dir`

Answer (score 13):

@[Johnson Lai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44363441/6494418)'s solution( `tensorboard --logdir=YOUR_LOG_DIR --host=127.0.0.1`) is works, just add `--host=127.0.0.1` at the command tail.

but you shoud replace `log_dir` with your own `log dir`.

**tips:** in `log dir`, log file(folder) likes `run-20180422085300`.

---

**here is my test!**

launch your cmd in anywhrer:

run commond `tensorboard --logdir [your log dir] --host=127.0.0.1`

or

launch your cmd with log dir, or commond `cd [your log dir]`

run commond `tensorboard --logdir ./ --host=127.0.0.1`

**I prefer the second method!**

Comment: if you launch tensorboard with server as `tensorboard --logdir ./`, you can use server `ip:port` to visited tensorboard in browser.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (running on docker), I was able to work it as follows:

First, make sure you start docker with `-p 6006:6006`.
Then, in Jupyter terminal, navigate to log dir and start tensorboard as:

```
tensorboard --logdir ./ --bind_all
```

You should see this output:
[image]

Now you can access the board on URL: http://localhost:6006/

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (It worked with me)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime, os

logs_base_dir = ".logs"
os.makedirs(logs_base_dir, exist_ok = True)
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}
```

from: https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-run-tensorboard-in-jupyter-notebook/